# Segmentation Core Fault Dumped in C - Fixed, RLE Compression

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, compression

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)

{
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int n;
    int p;
    FILE * fp;
    FILE * fptr;
    fp = fopen("financials.txt", "rt");
    fptr = fopen("compressed_financials.txt", "wt");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error file doesn't exist");

}   

while((n=fgetc(fp)))
{
    if(n == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }   
    else
    count[n]+=1;
}


for (p=0; p < 256; p++)
{
    if(count[p] > 0)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "%c%d", p, count[p]);
    }
}

fclose(fp);
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

Hello, when I am executing the program I get a Segementation fault (core dumped). What have I done incorrectly in my programming logic that causes this? From what I can understand, I might have used the pointers incorrectly which causes to access memory that doesn't exist. I am trying to implement RLE compression BTW.

I managed to get it to work now, RLE compression is half working but outputting the wrong structure. This is the characters in the input file "AAAAAA333333FFFFF22222" but then this is the compressed output: " 2536A6F5", the output should be "6A635F52" I think I need to implement more condition checking, can anybody give me hints what I need to add in my if statement so it prints it out correctly?

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Specifically how to use a debugger to catch the crash "in action" and locate when and where it happens in your program and what the values of all variables might be at that point.

Comment: Also note that the `"t"` in `"rt"` and `"wt"` is Microsoft-specific extension, it's not standard.

Comment: Lastly, what happens if you can't open the output file? Or, indeed, can't open the *input* file?

Comment: Ohh ok, let me try to get rid of that and see how it goes.

Comment: It's meant to print out 'Error reading file' when text file doesn't exist', I am going to manually create a text file.

Comment: Yes if the input file can't be opened you print an error message. And then what? Should you really continue with the program as if nothing happened?

Comment: The program should break, I forgot to insert a exit statement after fp==NULL

Comment: You should also check that `fptr != NULL`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help @Someprogrammerdude in fixing my programming logic now it executes without segmentation fault.

Comment: `count[n]+=1;` what is `count[n]` here ?    what if `n` value read from file is `1000` then it would be like accessing `count[1000]` but you declared only 256 as size of `count` array. probably you want to recheck this `count[n]+=1` statement.

Comment: I think the idea is to use the decimal value of ascii characters, which should be fine with a size of 256, no? And then they're printing that to a file if count[i] > 0.

Comment: @achal `n` is a single character pulled from [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) and loaded into an `int`. It will be in `[0..255]`, unless EOF is hit (which the OP checks for and breaks accordingly). In short, that part of this is ok.

Comment: Hello, my aim is to get RLE Compression working. This is the characters in the input file "AAAAAA333333FFFFF22222" but then this is the compressed output: "
2536A6F5", the output should be "6A635F22" I think I need to implement more condition checking, can anybody give me hints what I need to add in my if statement so it prints it out correctly?

Comment: Yep, sorry typo